# Changing the state management system of existing quasar application from vuex to pinia

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, pinia

Tried [this link](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/state-management-with-pinia) and created my first store in Quasar using Pinia,  I also needed to change the `.quasar/app.js` manually to add the Pinia store and to make Pinia functional.

```
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
import RootComponent from 'app/src/App.vue'

import createStore from 'app/src/stores/index'
import createRouter from 'app/src/router/index'

export default async function (createAppFn, quasarUserOptions) {
  // Create the app instance.
  // Here we inject into it the Quasar UI, the router & possibly the store.
  const app = createAppFn(RootComponent)
  app.config.devtools = true
  

  app.use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions)

    const store = typeof createStore === 'function'
      ? await createStore({})
      : createStore

    
      app.use(store)
  const router = markRaw(
    typeof createRouter === 'function'
      ? await createRouter({store})
      : createRouter
  )

    // make router instance available in store
    
      store.use(({ store }) => { store.router = router })

  // Expose the app, the router and the store.
  // Note that we are not mounting the app here, since bootstrapping will be
  // different depending on whether we are in a browser or on the server.
  return {
    app,
    store,
    router
  }
}
```

But the problem is `.quasar/app.js` is re-written with default contents as soon as `quasar dev` is executed and again I don't have access to the Pinia stores anymore.

As I said this application was based on vuex formerly.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @someuser Nope. Just created a new project and copied everything there!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the index file for pinia.

In "src/stores/index.js"

```
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Store instance.
 */

export default store((/* { ssrContext } */) => {
  const pinia = createPinia()

  // You can add Pinia plugins here
  // pinia.use(SomePiniaPlugin)

  return pinia
})
```

Try checking quasar info

```
quasar info
```

Notice @quasar/app-webpack and vuex.

If you are using @quasar/app, try to move to @quasar/app-webpack by upgrading quasar.

```
quasar upgrade -i
```

If you have vuex installed in your quasar info output, try to remove it.

```
npm uninstall vuex
```

In your package-lock.json, look for "node_modules/vuex" and delete the key and value.

Then delete your "node_modules" folder and run `npm i`

After that, run `quasar clean`.

You may try creating a Pinia store via quasar command to validate it.

```
quasar new store <store_name>
```

It should generate a pinia store instead of vuex store.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is older version of `@quasar/app-webpack` package. It got support for Pinia since v3.4.0. Check release notes [here](https://quasar.dev/start/release-notes). So basically upgrade this package.

Run `quasar upgrade -i` and then `quasar new store <store_name> [--format ts]`
It will create a `stores/` directory with pinia.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to remove and reinstall `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

In my case i didn't need to edit any special files, simply replace the `index.js` in the `stores` folder. To get quasar CLI to then use pinia when running `quasar new store` I had to use `quasar clean` and just like that I had fully transitioned.